# multidimensional csv

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file with php. I've always had situations where I know that the data is in a certain structure. However, I have a CSV where each row may have a different number of items in a row.

Here's a small example:

```
121, 32, 28, 23, 43   
322, 43, 43, 44  
435, 23, 43  
343, 56, 56, 678
```

I wanted to output something where I want to out it as such: 
First number in row 1, second number in row 1, 3rd number in row 1 - line break 
First number in row 1, second number in row 1, 4th number in row 1 - line break 
First number in row 1, second number in row 1, 5th number in row 1 - line break

First number in row 2, second number in row 2, 3rd number in row 2 - line break 
First number in row 1, second number in row 1, 4rd number in row 2 - line break

and so on........

I'm just having a hard time trying to figure out how to nest these loops.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you posted, I have came up with this mock up. I hope it helps.

```
$csv = array(
    array(121, 32, 28, 23, 43),
    array(322, 43, 43, 44),
    array(435, 23, 43),
    array(343, 56, 56, 678)
);

foreach($csv as $row){
    foreach($row as $key=>$column){
        if($key<2){
            continue;
        }
        echo $row[0].', '.$row[1].', '.$column.'<br>';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont get what is the problem.

You can read that file into 2-dimensional array.

```
$file = "file.csv";
$data_arr = array();

if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{

    $rownum = 1; // change to 0 to start counting from 0

    while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE)
    {

        $cellnum = 1; // change to 0 to start counting from 0

        foreach($row as $cell)
        {
            // optional charset conversion
            // $cell = iconv("windows-1250", "UTF-8", $cell);

            $data_arr[rownum][cellnum] = $cell;
            $cellnum++;
        }
        $rownum++;
    }
    fclose($handle); // close file

}
else
{
    echo "Error. Cant open ".$file;
}
```